# Yesod scaffold returns error "The application isn’t built"

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I am trying to learn Yesod and I started to have a look at https://www.yesodweb.com/book.

Before reading the book, I executed on my WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the instructions provided at https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart :

```
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
stack new yesod-book yesodweb/sqlite && cd yesod-book
stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc # install yesod cli
# updated the $PATH in my .zshrc and reloaded the terminal
stack build
stack test --flag yesod-book:library-only --flag yesod-book:dev
```

Compilation works with some warnings at `/mnt/d/Code/yesod_and_haskell/src/Model.hs:23:1: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]` but this does not prevent the examples to succeed.

However, when I run the development server

```
stack exec -- yesod devel
# ...
[12 of 12] Compiling Paths_yesod_book
yesod-book> copy/register
Installing library in /mnt/d/Code/yesod_and_haskell/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/f0163dccc19ddaa0efa9ec567b016ae57bd5477fab521d675f34f49ffd7923d3/9.2.7/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-9.2.7/yesod-book-0.0.0-11M4iC3bTuY3cNtaxd5kQS
Registering library for yesod-book-0.0.0..
Success! Waiting for next file change.
Type help for available commands. Press enter to force a rebuild.
```

When I connect to http://localhost:3000 I keep seeing

[image]

I tried to clear all the hidden folders containing build artifacts and rebuilding the project from scratch but this did not help.

```
stack --version
Version 2.9.1, Git revision 409d56031b4240221d656db09b2ba476fe6bb5b1 x86_64 hpack-0.35.0
yesod version  
yesod-bin version: 1.6.2.2
ghci version
GHCi, version 9.2.5
```

I am looking at past issues on github, but I am not sure about how to make them actionable for my problem:

- https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1517
- https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1755

The full configuration of my sample project can be found at [this repo](https://github.com/mberlanda/yesod_web_book/blob/578db949d445889c9b8b11b057c166f404074339/package.yaml)

How can I run my default application in devel mode?

Comment: What's the output of yesod devel when you press enter to force a rebuild? Does it work with GHCi instead (as I suggested in issue #1755)?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning before building and running:

`yesod-book$ stack clean && stack build && stack exec -- yesod devel`

Also make sure you have the required [System libraries](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) installed.

Comment: hi @sergiu-starciuc thanks for your hints. I ran `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev` but everything was already there. When I follow your instructions for cleaning build and re-running the service, I added the `-d` flag to yesod command but the only debug message I receive is `revProxy: appPort -1`. Do you have any hint for this?

Comment: On successful launch, the files "yesod-book.sqlite3", "yesod-book.sqlite3-wal" and "yesod-book.sqlite3-shm" should be created in the project root directory. In addition, SQL CREATE statements should be logged on first run. If you do not see them, the files and logs in terminal, then the problem is in the required libraries for SQLite. Perhaps you should install it by typing `$ sudo apt install sqlite3`.

Also make sure that all relevant ports for accessing the database are not filtered.

Comment: Also if you run a Docker container or WSL you may look at https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1428 and https://groups.google.com/g/yesodweb/c/ExT2qfS3bww

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. Sqlite3 is correctly installed in my WSL2 Ubuntu and I can find some databases generated by the test command ´yesod-book_test.sqlite3´ ´yesod-book_test.sqlite3-shm´ ´yesod-book_test.sqlite3-wal´. However none is generated by the yesod devel command. I do not see either any SQL related log when I run the application.

Comment: Out of my curiosity, could you please confirm that the code in https://github.com/mberlanda/yesod_web_book/tree/578db949d445889c9b8b11b057c166f404074339 does work for you (assuming that you have everything setup locally)? I imagine that the problem comes from my development environment.

Comment: The main difference that I have with issue #1428 and the other unanswered question is that the compiler claims that the application was built successfully `Success! Waiting for next file change.`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use WSL (I didn't know what it was until yesterday :). I run Yesod apps on Ubuntu and often get this error after pressing Ctrl-C, adding .cassius, .julius or errors in these files. Then I need to stop, clean up, build and execute again. Yesterday I even removed the PostgreSql library (libpq-dev) and got the same error as you. 
I'm assuming the issue is with WSL and the creation of the SQLite database. Try running an in-memory SQLite to see if the problem is file creation and not a port issue.
Sorry for disregarding "..WSL2..". I was inattentive when I read your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following @schoettl comment and [yesodweb/yesod/issues#1755](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1755), I tried to run the application from gchi instead of yesod bin.

```
$ stack ghci yesod-book:lib --no-load --work-dir .stack-work-devel
ghci> :l app/DevelMain.hs
ghci> DevelMain.update
```

This shown the logs described by @sergiu-starciuc comments

```
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"ident" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"password" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_user" UNIQUE ("ident"))
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "email"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"user_id" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES "user" ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,"verkey" VARCHAR NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_email" UNIQUE ("email"))
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "comment"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"message" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"user_id" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES "user" ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
Devel application launched: http://localhost:3000
ghci> 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2023:23:12:51 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

And the application worked as expected.